# Remove value within an array without removing duplicates

Tags: php

I'm doing an inventory system for a php game where the ids of items are stored in an variable on the database separated by a delimiter. For example: -1-1-1

```
foreach (array_keys($player_consumables, $use_item) as $key) {
unset($player_consumables[$key]);
}
```

This instance is removing all entries of the item. Instead of removing all of them, how would I make it remove just one of the duplicate entries?

Answer (score 0):

So what you wan't to do, is remove the first element with the value $use_item - right?

How about:

```
unset($player_consumables[array_search($use_item, $player_consumables)]);
```

And if you really need the `foreach` try:

```
foreach (array_keys($player_consumables, $use_item) as $key) {
    unset($player_consumables[$key]);
    break; // stop the foreach to only remove the first item
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That did exactly what I wanted. :D

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$newArray=array_unique($player_consumables);`